# gnuplot: How to remove last tic without losing auto calculation of tic separation?

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, is it possible to autocalculate tic frequency in `set xtics` and still remove a specific tick?

I want to draw a borderless arrow-through-origin coordinate system, this is still easy (showing only the x part to keep things simple):

```
unset border
set xtics axis no mirror
set arrow from minx,0 to maxx,0
```

With `minx` and `maxx` being two user-specified variables that are used to calculate all the sizes.

The problem with the tics is now that the arrow has a tip with a tic, which is ugly. So I want to remove only the last tic, but still have the autocalculate `ticfreq` feature of gnuplot. By specifying the tics by hand (`<start>,<increase>,<end>`) one loses the autocalculate feature. And by removing the tic with `set xtics add ('' XMAX)` one only hides the tic label, but not the tic bar.

**Is there any way to remove the last tic (bar and label) without giving up the auto calculation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command to remove a single tic bar. I would suggest a different approach: Extend the axes with a short arrow:

```
set style arrow 1 head filled size char 1.5,20,50 

unset border
set xzeroaxis lt -1
set yzeroaxis lt -1
set xtics nomirror axis
set ytics nomirror axis

set tmargin 2
set rmargin 4
set arrow 1 from graph 1,first 0 to screen 0.99,first 0 arrowstyle 1
set arrow 2 from first 0,graph 1 to first 0,screen 0.99 arrowstyle 1
plot x
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

This solution leaves you the autoscaling, but requires some tweaking of the arrow length and top and right margins.

Note, that the arrow length is automatically reduced if the arrow is shorter than twice the length. The dev version has a keyword `fixed` to prevent that, but the newest 4.6.5 doesn't know this.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems, I have to manually tweaking everytime a bit, depending on the specific task. Am I the only one finding it strange that gnuplot does not support auto-sized four-quadrant arrow-though-zero coordinate systems by default? This kind of system is the one everyone on the whole world is using starting from middle school...